# Youtube movie in android html application

Tags: android, html, youtube

I'm developing an app with html, css and javascript which i port trough Phonegap to play on an Android tablet. (android 2.3.1 Gingerbread)
Everything is working fine, except the Youtube embed.

If i place the iframe embed on my page there is no play-button above my youtubescreen, so the user does not know he has to press it. But if you press it, the movie loads into the external android video playing app.

But here's the second problem; when the movie ends, the external android player closes and returns to my app, but then my youtube video screen is black en has these ugly android videocontrols of the external player.

But i can't do anything with it... so the user can't press the movie to watch it again.

Does anybody know how to implement a youtube video correctly into an HTML based android application?

It's HTML, so webviews, videoview, intents and things won't work...

Things i tried:

- iframe embed
- object embed
- html5 video embed
- online embed on external page

but in every attempt, those ugly videocontrols keep popping up after the video ended. 
I also tried another player, but with the same result... Anyone ideas? :-)

Comment: Why do you want to embed the video? Likely it will be flash and therefore not supported? Or does YT gives you a HTML5 video?

Comment: how else can i implement a youtube video in my application?
I don't now what i get, html5 or flash, because i can't see the source code on my tablet...